# Scheme procedure with 2 arguments

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Learned to code C, long ago; wanted to try something new and different with Scheme.  I am trying to make a procedure that accepts two arguments and returns the greater of the two, e.g.

```
(define (larger x y)
  (if (> x y)
    x
    (y)))

(larger 1 2)
```

or,

```
(define larger
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (> x y)
      x (y))))

(larger 1 2)
```

I believe both of these are equivalent i.e. *if x > y, return x; else, return y*.

When I try either of these, I get errors e.g. *2 is not a function* or *error: cannot call: 2*

I've spent a few hours reading over SICP and TSPL, but nothing is jumping out (perhaps I need to use a "list" and reference the two elements via *car* and *cdr*?)

Any help appreciated.  If I am mis-posting, missed a previous answer to the same question, or am otherwise inappropriate, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that, differently from C and many other languages, in Scheme and all Lisp languages parentheses are an important part of the syntax.

For instance they are used for function call: `(f a b c)` means apply (call) function `f` to arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`, while `(f)` means apply (call) function `f` (without arguments).

So in your code `(y)` means apply the number `2` (the current value of `y`), but 2 is not a function, but a number (as in the error message).

Simply change the code to:

```
(define (larger x y)
  (if (> x y)
      x
      y))

(larger 1 2)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!  I verified that this worked.  I could see that the 2 is being treated like a function, but I could not understand why/how.  Definite bias coming from C.  Thanks, again. :-)